# Disable switchview animation not possible

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

Is it possible to disable the animation on switchview? Or even better to set a custom animation?

I did not find anything in the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `NoTransition` class, which seems to be made exactly for that purpose:

> "Null object" pattern implementation for transition. This object should be used instead of null reference to convey an absence of transition.

(Though I don't see any transition, if I don't set a `TransitionFactory`)

Comment: Its better not to set TransitionFactory.. indeed :) Thank you!!